# How to properly train multiple models simultenously pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement the actor-critic algorithm in **pytorch**. Hence I want to have two models and train them separately, namely:

```
actor = Net1()
critic = Net2()
```

My code looks like this:

```
optim_a = optim.SGD(actor.paramaters(), lr=.1, momentum=.9)
optim_c = optim.SGD(critic.paramaters(), lr=.1, momentum=.9)
for t in range(hours):
    optim_a.zero_grad()
    optim_c.zero_grad()
    allocation = actor(solar[t], B[t], load_left)
    load = load.detach()
    value = critic(solar[t], B[t], load_left)
    environment_instance = environment(solar[t], B[t], load, G1[t], G2[t])
    R[t], C[t], B[t+1] = environment_instance.step()
    load_left = load_left - allocation
    value_f = critic(solar[t+1], B[t+1], load_left)
    delta = R[t]+gamma*value_f-value
    delta = delta.detach()
    loss_critic = delta*value
    loss_actor = delta*torch.log(allocation)
    loss = loss_actor+loss_critic
    loss.backward()
    optim_a.step()
    optim_c.step()
```

Let me explain briefly the background (if it helps). I am working on load_assigment for a power system that uses solar energy. There is a fixed load and variable load. the environment is a class that runs the environment, that is, I give it some parameters and it outputs the reward (R). I use that to define delta. Then, I define both losses, where delta acts as a constant (no gradient should be propagated, that is why I detach it)

That code runs but the optimizer is not updating the weights. Strangely enough, sometimes they do update either the critic or actor (I have no idea why) but never both. I think this is odd because I've seen other tutorials where things like this are done, e.g. [GAN tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) but it is not working for me.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can give me some guidance.

Comment: It's hard to tell just from the code you provided. Multi models are a little tricky, even when they are cooperating, one model should not update the other model's parameter. I guess you've set `retain_graph=True` to work around that problem, but in nearly all cases it's unnecessary and using it just hides a bug. Instead you should  `.detach()` a tensor when crossing model boundaries at some (careful) point. Maybe [Actor-Critic-pytorch](https://github.com/yc930401/Actor-Critic-pytorch/blob/master/Actor-Critic.py#L59-L112) can get you some insight, that looks similar to what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, I took a look at the actor-critic algorithm they had. Their neural nets are not entirely independent, so that's not quite what I want. I'll try detach() to see if I can fix it with that. Otherwise I'll be back and include the exact code. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't work. I'll edit the original question.

Comment: It was working the entire time. I was just missreading the weight update. Something similar to what happened here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/gradients-exist-but-weights-not-updating/20484